# Rule out blank and null values in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, database-performance

Many times I have to run this query:

```
select * from users where name is not null and name != ''
```

Is there any better way to do this. I need more performance, any suggestion. I guess this is very common, so there may be some compiled function which will be something like

```
select * from users where name is present()
```

Using PostgreSQL 9 version.

Comment: [Postgres major versions include the first digit after the dot](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning). So, there is no "version 9". It's 9.0 or 9.1 or something. And I assume you mean "empty". "blank" may be confusing since there are no blanks (space characters) in an empty value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any `x`, `null != x` will be `null` and `null` is not `true`. That means that you can simply ignore NULLs in your case and say:

```
select * from users where name != ''
```

You could also convert NULLs to empty strings using COALESCE if that's clearer to you:

```
select * from users where coalesce(name, '') != ''
```

Of course that `coalesce` call isn't free.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e810c/2

Comment: `and null is false in a boolean context` ... That's a bit misleading. Let's just say: only `TRUE` qualifies in a `WHERE` clause (`FALSE` and `NULL` don't).

Comment: @Erwin: Perhaps "NULL isn't truthy" or "NULL is falsey". I'm trying to find a balance between pedantry and understandability for non-SQL people. My background is Mathematics so I love to be pedantic but...

Comment: The point is, unlike some other RDBMS Postgres implements a proper, fully functional, SQL-standard-compliant [`boolean` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html), which can be `NULL`, just like any other data type. And `NULL` is not `FALSE`. `NULL` is confusing to some, so I try to avoid such misleading statements. It just so happens that only `TRUE` qualifies in a `WHERE` clause. And I like your update. :)

Comment: @muistooshort: if you love to be pedantic ;) The "not equals" operator in standard SQL is `<>`. It just happens that all(?) DBMS also support the non-standard `!=`

Answer (score 1):

You can use NULLIF:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    USERS 
WHERE   NULLIF(NAME,'') IS NOT NULL
```